# When is a door not a door?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

May I ask any of you?

> A door is almost always a door, but some doors are not doors. When is a door not a door?

Comment: IIRC Stephen King used this one in the Dark Tower series, this must be the first English wordplay I ever knew. +1.

Comment: Wow I did *not* know that :O Too knowledgeable @Bass this is why you get all the answers to the puzzles ;)

Comment: @Bass Excellent series. Lots of good riddles in The Wasteland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is when it is

> Ajar

Haha.... :/

Comment: You too fast >:(

Comment: Is that a good thing, or a bad thing...

Comment: common child's joke